# How can I make an entire table background a certain color?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm not a dev in any way shape or form so this is probably super basic and my marketing education didn't cover it. But I'm setting up a webpage and what I am doing is trying to make the tables a certain color RGBA (25,25,150, 0.4). When I try to apply what I have, the highlight of the text is the color I want, but the overall table remains the same shade. [Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLaVR.png)

I've tried moving the rgba to several places including before the span and even in td style=", however all the wrong things are showing up with the color

````
            <h4><span style="vertical-align: middle; font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(219, 229, 241);">&nbsp;UNIMPORTANT TEXT</span></h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 45.2256%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
            <pre><span style="background-color: rgba(23, 23, 150, 0.4);" class="contentText">& IMPORTANT TEXT </span></pre>```
````

So basically I have a box with a light gray background. What I'm currently doing now just applies the the color to the highlight of the text, where I want it to apply to the background where the light grey background is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the background-color style in the `<td>` element:

```
<td style="background-color: rgba(23, 23, 150, 0.4);width: 45.2256%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
    <pre><span style="" class="contentText">& IMPORTANT TEXT </span></pre>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace rgb(219, 229, 241)with something else. You can just say red green blue orange etc. Or you can use a css color picker and use something like a hexadecimal #2c2c2c

Comment: rgb(...) is valid syntax, how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

```html
<div style="background-color: rgba(23, 23, 150, 0.4);">
     <h4><span style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(219, 229, 241);">&nbsp;UNIMPORTANT TEXT</span></h4>
     <table>
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 45.2256%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
      <pre><span class="contentText">& IMPORTANT TEXT </span></pre>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>      
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite, ideally the entire background of the box will be that color.The image I posted was what was going on when I attempted to do so. Sorry but I'm not a comp sci person at all =/